# Get the value from object of a class by property name dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic

I want to write a method that should return the value from an `object` for the specified property.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
}


public int GetValue(string field)
{
     MyClass obj=new MyClass();
     obj=FromDb(); //get value from db
     dynamic temp=obj;
     return temp?.field;
}
```

The above code is only to demonstrate to what I am looking for.

Here I want to pass the `property` name (i.e a/b/c/d as per my above code) as an input to the method `GetValue` and it should return the value of that property.

This code is compiling successfully, but in run time it will search for the property name `field` not the value of field variable.

Any suggestions or workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the value:

```
public int GetValue(string field)
{
     MyClass obj = new MyClass();
     obj = FromDb(); //get value from db
     var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(field);
     return (int)property.GetValue(obj);
}
```

Comment: I was suggesting the same but since you answer came up before mine I just upvote your ;)

Comment: Thank you so much I am going to try it out, just worrying about performance will it have any impact?

Comment: @TufanChand - Yes, there will be a performance hit. Whether it will impact your application is hard to say. You'll probably want to measure the performance and make sure you're happy with it.

Comment: @Sean, ok understood, I will take care of that. Thank you very much for your help.